# How to add a default ordering of ListEntries table in Backpack for Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

When a user first visits the page, the `ListEntries` table is ordered ascending by id and none of the ordering icons in the table header are active.

I would like to have the `ListEntries` table ordered by a column of my choosing, including having the icon next to this column active (either ascending or descending).

Is there a way to have the `ListEntries` table ordered by a column of my choosing when a user visits the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by manipulating the request object, which may be frowned upon in some circles.

This solution will also update the order icon on the appropriate column.

There are a number of ways to accomplish this, but one way would be to add the following to the `setupListOperation()` method of your Controller.

```
/** @var \Illuminate\Http\Request $request */
$request = $this->crud->getRequest();
if (!$request->has('order')) {
    $request->merge(['order' => [
        [
            'column' => 'column-index-here',
            'dir' => 'asc'
        ]
    ]]);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your Controller's `setup()` method you can use:

```php
$this->crud->orderBy('name', 'DESC');
```

Anything you pass to the `orderBy()` statement will be used on the Eloquent query.

By default, columns for real attributes (that have a correspondent column in the database) should be `orderable`. But you can also manually specify `'orderable' => true` for columns, or [define your own order logic](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.6/crud-columns#custom-order-logic). Note that relationship columns (1-n, n-n), `model_function` or `model_function` columns are NOT orderable by default, but you *can* make them orderable with `orderLogic`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works, but it won't update the order icon in the view (next to the column label). Is there a way to have this displayed?

Comment: Can you give a sample orderLogic for 1-n relationship.  From many values, we select first one for particular condition.

Answer (score 2):

Use this key `orderable` it is a boolean

```
 this->crud->addColumn([
   'label'      => 'Category',
   'type'       => 'select',
   'name'       => 'category_id', // the db column for the foreign key
   'entity'     => 'category', // the method that defines the relationship in your Model
   'attribute'  => 'name', // foreign key attribute that is shown to user
   'orderable'  => true,
   'orderLogic' => function ($query, $column, $columnDirection) {
        return $query->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'articles.select')
            ->orderBy('categories.name', $columnDirection)->select('articles.*');
    }
]);
```

[Reference](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-columns#custom-order-logic-for-columns)